# htaccess rewrite rule (arbitrarily path to index.php)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

is it somehow possible to have a pattern which represents any path sequence which substitutes to my index.php with a parameter which holds the given path?

I have this rule 
`RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]`

With that it is possible to extend my URL with one more "Directory": www.example.com/Home for example. It redirects to index.php and the get variable shows me "Home".

Now i wanna improve this, so it is possible to do something like www.example.com/path/to/somewhere which redirects also to my index.php and the variable shows "path/to/somewhere". It should allow to use an arbitrarily amount of slashes and "directory" entries.
BUT! all URLs which got a file on its end, i.e. www.example.com/path/to/file.pdf should be uneffected of this rewrite rule.

How can i achive that?

Answer (score 0):

Try following one

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?path=$1 [NC,L]
```

And in index.php, access path as below

```
<?php
echo $_GET['path'];
?>
```

Comment: The page variable always shows me index.php, not more. And even *.jpg and other urls will be redirected to index.php.

Comment: Updated my answer, please check at your end

Comment: Tanks again. Now the variable is always empty and files are still redirected.

Comment: Its working perfectly fine in my environment, I have pasted content of my index.php in the answer